# Using materialize how do i center a tabs in nav-content

Tags: html, css, materialize

https://i.stack.imgur.com/RsvGd.png
So basically i am having an issue. I have no problem in moving any of the tabs to the right or left side. But when i try to center all the tabs i'm having no luck.
So in the image above i am trying to get TEST 1, TEST 2, DISABLED TAB AND TEST 4 to be centered on the page.

I am using the Extended Navbar with Tabs example on their website.

````
    <div class="nav-wrapper">
      <a href="#" class="brand-logo">Logo</a>
      <a href="#" data-target="mobile-demo" class="sidenav-trigger"><i class="material-icons">menu</i></a>
      <ul id="nav-mobile" class="right hide-on-med-and-down">
        <li><a href="sass.html">Sass</a></li>
        <li><a href="badges.html">Components</a></li>
        <li><a href="collapsible.html">JavaScript</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="nav-content">
      <ul class="tabs tabs-transparent">
        <li class="tab"><a href="#test1">Test 1</a></li>
        <li class="tab"><a class="active" href="#test2">Test 2</a></li>
        <li class="tab disabled"><a href="#test3">Disabled Tab</a></li>
        <li class="tab"><a href="#test4">Test 4</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>```
````

Answer (score 0):

You can use display flex on tabs-transparent class, justify-content: center will position them horizontally and as extra align-items: center will position them vertically.

```css
.tabs-transparent {
display:flex;
align-items: center;
justify-content: center;
}
```

````html
<div class="nav-wrapper">
      <a href="#" class="brand-logo">Logo</a>
      <a href="#" data-target="mobile-demo" class="sidenav-trigger"><i class="material-icons">menu</i></a>
      <ul id="nav-mobile" class="right hide-on-med-and-down">
        <li><a href="sass.html">Sass</a></li>
        <li><a href="badges.html">Components</a></li>
        <li><a href="collapsible.html">JavaScript</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="nav-content">
      <ul class="tabs tabs-transparent">
        <li class="tab"><a href="#test1">Test 1</a></li>
        <li class="tab"><a class="active" href="#test2">Test 2</a></li>
        <li class="tab disabled"><a href="#test3">Disabled Tab</a></li>
        <li class="tab"><a href="#test4">Test 4</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>```
````